# Unexpected sort order for answers

Tags: support

My understanding is that answers are meant to be displayed in the following order:

- Accepted answer, if any.
- Highest voted answer.
- Second highest voted answer.
- Etc.

I am regularly seeing new, unaccepted answers with few votes listed above high-voted answers. I am wondering if this is a widely-seen bug, a rarely-seen bug or if I have some misunderstanding.

Comment: BTW: Answers with the same number of votes are presented in random order which changes with every view. And: Self-accepted answers are not placed on top, but sorted as normal after the number of votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three sorting options.

You just described the "votes" order; however, answers can also be sorted by "activity" and by "oldest." It may be a bug, or it may simply that you've clicked a different sorting order.

Comment: Ugh, now I feel silly for not noticing those tabs before. I must have clicked on them a few times.